# Progress bar in parallel loop invocation

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task-parallel-library, async-await

I am trying to update a progressbar in a multithreaded environment. I know that a lot of questions already treat that question but none of the proposed solution have worked for me.
Here is  the backbone of my code :

```
public static void DO_Computation(//parameters) {
  //Intialisation of parameters

  Parallel.For(struct initialisation with local data) {
    //business logic
    //Call to update_progressbar (located in an another class, as the DO_Computation function is in Computation.cs class (not deriving from Form). 
    WinForm.Invoke((Action)delegate {Update_Progress_Bar(i);}); //WinForm is a class that exposes the  progressbar.
  }
}
```

This is not working (the progressbar is freezing when arriving at 100%, which is normal (we can  refer to the [microsoft article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997392%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in this matter (indeed, this is not a thread-safe operating method)).
The Microsoft site stiplates to wrap the `Parallel.For` loop into a `Task` routine as follows:

```
public static void DO_Computation(//parameters) {
  //Intialisation of parameters
  Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
  {
    Parallel.For(struct initialosation with local data) {
      //business logic
      //Call to update_progressbar (ocated in an another class, as the DO_Computation function is in Computation.cs class (not deriving from Form). 
      WinForm.Invoke((Action)delegate {Update_Progress_Bar(i);}); //WinForm is a class that exposes the  progressbar.
      ..
    }
  });
});
```

However this is not working as well, when debugging the thread is getting out of the Task scope directly.

**EDIT 2:**

Basically, my problem is divided in 3 parts: `Computation.cs` (where `DO_Computation` is exposed), `WinForm` which is the form containing the progress bar, and `MainWindow` which is the form that contains the button which when clicked opens the form with the progress bar.

I do not clearly understand what is the use of "Task" in this case.
Because it is going out of the Task scope without performing any `Parallel.For` work

Any ideas?

Many Thanks,

> **EDIT 3:**

I upgraded my code with the help of  Noseratio (thans a lot to him). However I have the same problem which is the code inside task is never executed.  My code now looks like :

`DoComputation method
   //Some Initilasations here 
    Action enableUI = () =>
    {
    frmWinProg.SetProgressText("Grading Transaction...");
    frmWinProg.ChangeVisibleIteration(true);
    };
    Action<Exception> handleError = (ex) =>
    {
    // error reporting
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    };
    var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    var token = cts.Token;
    Action cancel_work = () =>
    {
    frmWinProg.CancelTransaction();
    cts.Cancel();
    };
    var syncConext = SynchronizationContext.Current;
    Action<int> progressReport = (i) =>
    syncConext.Post(_ => frmWinProg.SetIteration(i,GrpModel2F.NumOfSim, true), null);
    var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
    ParallelLoopResult res = Parallel.For<LocalDataStruct>(1,NbSim, options,
    () => new DataStruct(//Hold LocalData for each thread),
    (iSim, loopState, DataStruct) => 
    //Business Logic 
    if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
    loopState.Stop();
    }
    progressReport(iSim);
    //Business Logic
    return DataStruct;
    },
    (DataStruct) => 
    //Assiginig Results;
    });//Parallel.For end
    }, token, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning, TaskScheduler.Default);
    task.ContinueWith(_ =>
    {
    try
    {
    task.Wait();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    while (ex is AggregateException && ex.InnerException != null)
    ex = ex.InnerException;
    handleError(ex);
    }
    enableUI();
    }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext`

());

Note that the Do_Computation function is itself called from  a Form that runs a BackGroundWorker on it.

Comment: Please format the code so it actually is readable.

Comment: Found where the problem was coming from ( a delegate in the upper part of the code was making the whole thing working on an another thread.Thus, making calls to  the `frmWinProg` created on an another thread was causing the deadlock in the end. Thanks for your help, it was much appreciated

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`async/await`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/async-await/info), [`Progress<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh193692%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and observe cancellation with [`CancellationTokenSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtokensource%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

A good read, related: ["Async in 4.5: Enabling Progress and Cancellation in Async APIs"](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/async-in-4-5-enabling-progress-and-cancellation-in-async-apis/).

If you need to target .NET 4.0 but develop with VS2012+ , you still can use `async/await`, Microsoft provides the [`Microsoft.Bcl.Async`](http://www.nuget.org/packages/microsoft.bcl.async) library for that.

I've put together a WinForms example illustrating all of the above. It also shows how to observe cancellation for `Parallel.For` loop, using `ParallelLoopState.Stop()`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication_22487698
{
    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        IEnumerable<int> _data = Enumerable.Range(1, 100);
        Action _cancelWork;

        private void DoWorkItem(
            int[] data,
            int item,
            CancellationToken token,
            IProgress<int> progressReport,
            ParallelLoopState loopState)
        {
            // observe cancellation
            if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                loopState.Stop();
                return;
            }

            // simulate a work item
            Thread.Sleep(500);

            // update progress
            progressReport.Report(item);
        }

        private async void startButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // update the UI
            this.startButton.Enabled = false;
            this.stopButton.Enabled = true;

            try
            {
                // prepare to handle cancellation
                var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
                var token = cts.Token;

                this._cancelWork = () =>
                {
                    this.stopButton.Enabled = false;
                    cts.Cancel();
                };

                var data = _data.ToArray();
                var total = data.Length;

                // prepare the progress updates
                this.progressBar.Value = 0;
                this.progressBar.Minimum = 0;
                this.progressBar.Maximum = total;

                var progressReport = new Progress<int>((i) =>
                {
                    this.progressBar.Increment(1);
                });

                // offload Parallel.For from the UI thread 
                // as a long-running operation
                await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    Parallel.For(0, total, (item, loopState) =>
                        DoWorkItem(data, item, token, progressReport, loopState));
                    // observe cancellation
                    token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                }, token, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning, TaskScheduler.Default);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }

            // update the UI
            this.startButton.Enabled = true;
            this.stopButton.Enabled = false;
            this._cancelWork = null;
        }

        private void stopButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (this._cancelWork != null)
                this._cancelWork();
        }
    }
}
```

**Updated**, here's how to do the same without `async/await`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication_22487698
{
    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        IEnumerable<int> _data = Enumerable.Range(1, 100);
        Action _cancelWork;

        private void DoWorkItem(
            int[] data,
            int item,
            CancellationToken token,
            Action<int> progressReport,
            ParallelLoopState loopState)
        {
            // observe cancellation
            if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                loopState.Stop();
                return;
            }

            // simulate a work item
            Thread.Sleep(500);

            // update progress
            progressReport(item);
        }

        private void startButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // update the UI
            this.startButton.Enabled = false;
            this.stopButton.Enabled = true;

            Action enableUI = () =>
            {
                // update the UI
                this.startButton.Enabled = true;
                this.stopButton.Enabled = false;
                this._cancelWork = null;
            };

            Action<Exception> handleError = (ex) =>
            {
                // error reporting
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            };

            try
            {
                // prepare to handle cancellation
                var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
                var token = cts.Token;

                this._cancelWork = () =>
                {
                    this.stopButton.Enabled = false;
                    cts.Cancel();
                };

                var data = _data.ToArray();
                var total = data.Length;

                // prepare the progress updates
                this.progressBar.Value = 0;
                this.progressBar.Minimum = 0;
                this.progressBar.Maximum = total;

                var syncConext = SynchronizationContext.Current;

                Action<int> progressReport = (i) =>
                    syncConext.Post(_ => this.progressBar.Increment(1), null);

                // offload Parallel.For from the UI thread 
                // as a long-running operation
                var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    Parallel.For(0, total, (item, loopState) =>
                        DoWorkItem(data, item, token, progressReport, loopState));
                    // observe cancellation
                    token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                }, token, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning, TaskScheduler.Default);

                task.ContinueWith(_ => 
                {
                    try
                    {
                        task.Wait(); // rethrow any error
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        while (ex is AggregateException && ex.InnerException != null)
                            ex = ex.InnerException;
                        handleError(ex);
                    }
                    enableUI();
                }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                handleError(ex);
                enableUI();
            }
        }

        private void stopButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (this._cancelWork != null)
                this._cancelWork();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Noseratio. Unfortunately, I would not be able to use your solurion for several reason : first of all, the software was developed using .NET 4.0 and I also cannot download Microsoft.Bcl.Async (company's privacy). Is it possible to do this without the async/wait and IProgress routines? Many Thanks.

Comment: @VLT, yes, it's possible to use `Task.ContinueWith` instead of `await`. The code would be much bulkier though, and you won't be able to use liner code flow.

Comment: Tried everything, I beleive .. It is still not working. Have the same behaviour in the case of task => going out of the Task scope without doing any work in the parallel for loop

Comment: Thank you very much ! But I believe that Progress (aswell as the IProgress interface were intorduced in .Net 4.5) thus I do not have access to them  :(

Comment: @VLT, indeed they were, I missed that. Check my update for an alternative solution. It's pretty sad that you're restrained from using `Microsoft.Bcl.Async`, which has `Progress<T>`.

Comment: Thank you a lot. However, it is stil not working I edit my question