# Simple way to introduce async during a heavy loading op

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, async-await, .net-4.5

I'm working on a WinForm application that has to load a lot of data from a cloud database at the very beginning. This causes a blank form to appear hanged for as long as 20 seconds. I've tried a few ways to boots trap the app by using C++ based loading screens but the solutions are not elegant and are not acceptable by team leads. I've used BachgroundWorker a lot. here is my code in question:

```
private void ConfigurePWR_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        // Initializing logging (2-5 second delay)

        // Initializing security manager (3-7 second delay)

        // Load data from DB (10-30 second delay)
        ReloadData(0);
    }
    catch (Exception exp)
    {
        UiElements.ShowErrorMessageBox(this, "Loading failure. Cannot continue.", exp);
        Close();
    }      
}

private void ReloadData(byte caseSelector)
{
    switch (caseSelector)
    {
        case 0:
            LoadConnectors();
            LoadPolicies();
            LoadOrganizationDirectories();
            LoadProxyConfig();
            break;
        case 1:
            LoadConnectors();
            break;
        case 2:
            LoadPolicies();
            break;
        case 3:
            LoadOrganizationDirectories();
            break;
        case 4:
            LoadProxyConfig();
            break;
    }
}
```

Now, each `Load*` method is actually assigning that BindingSource with a datasource. So, thats where the change to one of the form control is made. I'm trying to handle the async in such a way that I make least changes here.

Is there a recommended way to do this? Last time I tried Async-Await, I ended up writing a wrapper over async-await that did well async-await. It gets confusing very fast. I don't want to repeat that as I had the async keyword added to just about every method in my form's code.

Comment: How about returning a Task<T>?

Comment: Can you give me a pointer to an(y) article on this, please?

Comment: I'm looking at a few right now. Seems like Task<T> approach follows the return-a-thing concept. I want the Data sources set and the controls enabled. I'll try to put a loading screen to block any interaction. Just dont want a dead UI.

Comment: You do not expect a return value, you don't need to return a Task. Simply adding async like this does not work? `private async void ConfigurePWR_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)`

Comment: @HassanGulzar Noseratio wrote in his answer everything.

Answer (score 4):

If your business logic provides `Task`-based asynchronous APIs, use them. If it doesn't, offload it to a pool thread with `Task.Run` to keep the UI responsive. Use `Task.Factory.StartNew` w/ `TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning` instead of `Task.Run` if the synchronous operation takes substantial amount of time. You may want to observe cancellation, too.

I've recently posted an example of this for a WinForms app (the concept itself is not specific to WinForms): https://stackoverflow.com/a/22497438/1768303.

Comment: I saw the code and I believe it will work and should really be given as a starter template to anyone new to async and TPL. I however need to research a bit more as I'm doing text file reading to SQL database. And I'm using chunks. So, read 200 lines from text file line-by-line to a in-code-DataTable and then process the datatable in a separate method which has the commit statement and just kills the UI. and resume reading from text file till the next 200

Comment: @HassanGulzar, hope it helped. If not, feel free to clarify any points.

Comment: Oh, it did helped. Just figuring if I need the Parallel.For as I'm reading a text file and used the `File.ReadLines(_selectedDataFilePath).Count()' to get a rough idea of total records.

Comment: @HassanGulzar, no you don't need `Parallel.For` for that. It's good for calculation-intensive, CPU-bound work. `Task.Run` would be enough for what you do.