# Run .exe processes in parallel and update progress bar in .NET 4.5

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, process, progress-bar

I have a dataGridView where I run a Process for each entry 
and then update a toolStripProgressBar based on the output from the Process.

I have looked at the following threads,

[Run two async tasks in parallel and collect results in .NET 4.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12343081/run-two-async-tasks-in-parallel-and-collect-results-in-net-4-5)

[Progress bar in parallel loop invocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22487698/progress-bar-in-parallel-loop-invocation)

[how to update the progress bar from tasks running concurrently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23463114/how-to-update-the-progress-bar-from-tasks-running-concurrently)

but I am not sure how to change my current code to something along these lines.
The main difference from these threads, as I see it, is that my computations are done by an outside application,
which I then need to collect the output from.
I guess I have to define each Process as an async task and then somehow collect the output.

For simplicity the processes are equal weighted in the sample code.

```
private iNumProcesses; 
private void RunApps()
{
    iNumProcesses = dataGridView1.Rows.Count;
    string sPath = .exe application path    
    for (int i = 0; i < iNumProcesses; i++)
    {   
        string sArgs = dataGridView1.Rows[i]["Arguments"].ToString();
        ExecuteProgram(sPath, sArgs);
    }
}
private void ExecuteProgram(string sProcessName, string sArgs) 
{
    using (cmd = new Process())
    {
        cmd.StartInfo.FileName = sProcessName;
        cmd.StartInfo.Arguments = sArgs;
        cmd.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        cmd.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        cmd.StartInfo.ErrorDialog = true;
        cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        cmd.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(SortOutputHandler);
        cmd.ErrorDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(SortOutputHandler);
        cmd.Start();
        cmd.BeginOutputReadLine();
        while (!cmd.HasExited) { Application.DoEvents(); }
    }        
}
private void SortOutputHandler(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    Trace.WriteLine(e.Data);
    this.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(() =>
    {
        if (e.Data == "Start") { do something... }
        else if (e.Data == "Finish") { do something... }
        else if (e.Data == "End")   { do something... }
        else
        {
            // .exe application output numbers 1 through 100
            toolStripProgressBar1.Value += Math.Round(Convert.ToInt32(e.Data)/iNumProcesses,0);
        }
    }));
}
```

How can I run the processes in parallel and update the progress bar 
based on the output numbers 1 through 100 I get from the .exe applications?
Any advice or suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

My answer to this question is *not* particularly associated with "C#" and therefore I'm not going to speak directly in those terms:   this unexpectedly-thorny issue is actually universal.

- The *first* thing that you must do is to arrange to periodically update the user display. To avoid nasty race-conditions and other problems, you should have "the main thread" perform this task, driven by a millisecond timer. The thread consults a shared array of progress-information and updates *all* of the progress-bars accordingly. *(If you want to use an event to avoid outright "timed waiting," feel free to do so.)*
- Since each of the launched child processes will have their own input and output streams, and will be writing to those streams asynchronously, you will find it necessary to *spawn a "mommy thread"* within your application to supervise each child.  This *thread* corresponds to a particular external *process,* and, in fact, is the one that launches it.  The thread continues to exist until it determines that the process that it launched has died.
- The "mommy thread" observes the output-stream(s) of its appointed ward to determine its "progress." It updates the progress-variables in the shared array accordingly. (A key element of this design is that each "mommy thread" is able to pay 100% of its attention to just *its* child. And, because all the "mommies" are *threads,* they can easily share information with the thread that's updating those progress bars.)
- Do you *actually* have to use semaphores-and-such to coordinate access between the mommy-threads and the main? Depending of course upon the exact internal implementation of that data-structure, the answer just might be, "probably *not."* (Oh, but it's probably safest to do it anyway.)